# I need to find a python.exe file in either anaconda or python but am unable to do so

Tags: python, github

I'm working with a project on github that requires that I have a python.exe file because the program doesn't have python installed on it. However, I am struggling to find this file when I search for it.

Link to the project: 
https://github.com/titu1994/Neural-Style-Transfer

In the project: "Upon first run, it will request the python path. Traverse your directory to locate the python.exe of your choice (Anaconda is tested)"